# django - Multiple Login instances from the same browser raises CSRF Token Missing

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a working django auth system.

I have opened two tabs on which my login page is loaded. I logged into the website on one of the tabs. When I try to login using a different account, it raises csrf token missing exception.

Comment: csrf token changes with each request. So if you login in one tab, the value of the expected csrf token changes, and that makes the token in the other tab invalid. If you could use any value of the csrf token, that would defeat the purpose of csrf.

Comment: Sure that makes sense. How to take care of this then... We need to give the ability for multiple account holders to login in the same browser.